# Appstore - Export compliance as an individual?

Tags: iphone, ssl, appstore-approval

If I want to use ssl in an iphone app, I need an Encryption Registration Number (ERN) to publish it. I have read similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633957/iphone-export-compliance-when-outside-the-u-s) where I have found very useful tips. However, [applying for snap-r](https://snapr.bis.doc.gov/registration/Register.do) asks for a company name that, as an individual developer, I don't have. Do I need to create a company in order to use ssl or there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same name under which yours apps appear in the app store.

You have probably seen this.. but this guy is an individual developer who went through the process.

http://tigelane.blogspot.com/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html

Comment: Already did but I forgot to update this question. Let's accept the answer then